# Parsing JSON script

Tags: html, json, xml, api

I have made this sharing function for LinkedIn. This is working fine. I saw in their API that you could "share with specifik values":

> https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/share-on-linkedin

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <!--<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.5b1.js"></script>-->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://platform.linkedin.com/in.js">
    api_key: myAPIkey
    authorize: true
    onLoad: shareContent
    </script>

</head>
<body>

    <script type="in/Share">
    </script>

    <script>
            // Setup an event listener to make an API call once auth is complete
            function onLinkedInLoad() {
                IN.Event.on(IN, "auth", shareContent);
            }

            // Handle the successful return from the API call
            function onSuccess(data) {
                console.log(data);
            }

            // Handle an error response from the API call
            function onError(error) {
                console.log(error);
            }

            // Use the API call wrapper to share content on LinkedIn
            function shareContent() {

                // Build the JSON payload containing the content to be shared
                var payload = {
                    "comment": "Sundhedsbogen http://www.google.dk",

                    "visibility": {
                        "code": "anyone"
                    }
                }

                IN.API.Raw("/people/~/shares?format=json")
                .method("POST")
                .body(JSON.stringify(payload))
                .result(onSuccess)
                .error(onError);
            }


    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

I tried to add this instead:

```
// Build the JSON payload containing the content to be shared
                var payload = {
                    "comment": "Check out developer.linkedin.com!",
                    "content": {
                        "title": "LinkedIn Developers Resources",
                        "description": "Leverage LinkedIn's APIs to maximize engagement",
                        "submitted-url": "https://developer.linkedin.com",  
                        "submitted-image-url": "https://example.com/logo.png"
                    },
                    "visibility": {
                        "code": "anyone"
                    }  
                }
```

**Web.config**

```
<share>
  <comment>Check out developer.linkedin.com!</comment>
  <content>
    <title>LinkedIn Developer Resources</title>
    <description>Leverage LinkedIn's APIs to maximize engagement</description>
    <submitted-url>https://developer.linkedin.com</submitted-url>
    <submitted-image-url>https://example.com/logo.png</submitted-image-url>
  </content>
  <visibility>
    <code>anyone</code>
  </visibility>
</share>
```

But nothing happens when I add this. I get the exact same box up, where I can share a comment on the link. But no picture, title or description.

Does anybody have an idea how I can solve this?